# How to read columns from a CSV file and store them in a struct? C Language

Tags: c

I have this file for example:

```
Aluno;p1;p2
Joao;5.5;2.1
Maria;8.0;7.5
Jose;9.5;9.5
```

and I need to read this file, and store it in a struct, like this:

```
struct aluno
{
    char nome[10];
    char p1;
    char p2;
};
```

My code: (I don't know how to proceed anymore)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct aluno
{
    char nome[10];
    char p1;
    char p2;
} dict;

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    dict aluno[9];
    char nomeArq[10];

    printf("Enter the file name: ");
    scanf("%10[^\n]", nomeArq);

    if ((fp = fopen(nomeArq, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error %s\n", nomeArq);
        return 1;
    }
    char buffer[1024];
    int field = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (fgets(buffer, 1024, fp) != NULL)
    {
        char *token = strtok(buffer, ";");
        while (token)
        {
            if (campoCount == 0)
            {
                strcpy(aluno[i].nome, token);
            }
            if (campoCount == 1)
            {
                strcpy(aluno[i].p1, token);
            }
            if (campoCount == 2)
            {
                strcpy(aluno[i].p2, token);
            }
            token = strtok(NULL, ";");
            campoCount++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    printAlunos(aluno);

    return 0;
}

void printAlunos(dict aluno[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", aluno[i].nome);
        printf("%s %s\n", aluno[i].p1, aluno[i].p2);
    }
}
```

PS: The header must be included

```
Aluno;p1;p2
```

I did a lot of research in the last few days, and all the tutorials I found were reading CSV files that didn't have columns, and for that reason, didn't work in my code. I don't know what else to do. This is an excel spreadsheet, for the record

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where did you ever see a CSV file without columns? Or a tutorial for such a file? If there are no values separated it's not a CSV file. Please show one tutorial or Question on StackOverflow where you think it does not match for files with columns. Are you aware that for solving the problem, it does not matter if you separate using commas or semi colons? They work the same way.

Comment: At first glance your code looks not too bad. What's wrong with your code? Does it work or not? The only real big problem I saw at first glance is that you use `strcpy` to copy a string into a `char`. `p1` and `p2` should also be declared as array, like `char p1[10]` instead of `char p1`.

Comment: `campoCount` variable is fishy : I don't see it's declaration and I don't see it set to 0 at the beginning of each "csv" line.

Comment: Why do you think `5.5` and `2.1` will fit in a `char p1, p2`? They won't. The values look like floating point values, so `float p1, p2;` would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can keep count in a loop and use `strtok()`, it is much simpler to use `sscanf()` to parse all values from your read buffer into your struct at once.

Your current struct with `char p1, p2` does not match your data (e.g. `5.5;2.1`) Neither of those floating-point values can be captured in a `char`. It would make things far easier to read the 2nd two values into a `float` instead, e.g.

```c
#define MAXNM    10       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXAL   128
#define MAXC   1024

typedef struct aluno {
    char nome[MAXNM];
    float p1, p2;         /* p1, p2 changed to float to match data */
} dict;
```

Here you can simply create an array of `dict` to hold all values in your file, for example:

```c
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  
  char buf[MAXC];         /* buffer to hold line */
  size_t n = 0;           /* array index counter */
  dict arr[MAXAL] = {{ .nome = "" }};     /* array of dict initialized zero */
  /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
  FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
```

After reading and discarding the 1st line of data (the headings row), you can loop reading and separating all data in the file quite easily:

```c
  /* while array not full and line read */
  while (n < MAXAL && fgets (buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
    /* parse values from buf into struct */
    if (sscanf (buf, "%9[^;];%f;%f", 
                arr[n].nome, &arr[n].p1, &arr[n].p2) == 3) {
      n += 1;   /* increment index counter on successful parse */
    }
  }
```

That's all that is needed for the read and parse of each value from the line into a struct filling your array of struct.

A complete example reading your data file could be:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXNM    10       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXAL   128
#define MAXC   1024

typedef struct aluno {
    char nome[MAXNM];
    float p1, p2;         /* p1, p2 changed to float to match data */
} dict;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  
  char buf[MAXC];         /* buffer to hold line */
  size_t n = 0;           /* array index counter */
  dict arr[MAXAL] = {{ .nome = "" }};     /* array of dict initialized zero */
  /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
  FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

  if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
    perror ("file open failed");
    return 1;
  }
  
  if (!fgets (buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {   /* read/discard 1st line of headings */
    return 1;
  }
  
  /* while array not full and line read */
  while (n < MAXAL && fgets (buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
    /* parse values from buf into struct */
    if (sscanf (buf, "%9[^;];%f;%f", 
                arr[n].nome, &arr[n].p1, &arr[n].p2) == 3) {
      n += 1;   /* increment index counter on successful parse */
    }
  }
  
  if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
    fclose (fp);
  
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {  /* output results */
    printf ("%-10s  %.2f  %.2f\n", arr[i].nome, arr[i].p1, arr[i].p2);
  }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in the file `dat/aluno.txt` you could do:

```
$ ./bin/readaluno dat/aluno.txt
Joao        5.50  2.10
Maria       8.00  7.50
Jose        9.50  9.50
```

Showing each value from each line was successfully separated into your struct and then all structs containing data in your array were output. Much easier that trying to keep track of what `strtok()` iteration you are on with a `switch` statement (and much less error prone).

Let me know if you have further questions.